# I am getting 'NoneType object is not subscriptable' error in web scraping method

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
import os
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

streamings = dict(
    amazon='amp',
    disney='dnp',
    darkmatter='dkm',
    rakuten_viki='vik',
    hbo='hbm',
    netflix='nfx',
    hulu='hlu',
    paramount='pmp',
    funimation='fmn',
    crunchyroll='cru',
    starz='stz',
    appletv='atp'
)

url = "https://apis.justwatch.com/graphql"

headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.32",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
}

with open('postData.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    post_data = json.load(file)
with open('query.graphql', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    query = file.read()
post_data['query'] = query

def set_streaming(key: str):
    """ Set the streaming on query variables. """
    
    post_data['variables']['popularTitlesFilter']['packages'] = [streamings[key]]

clusters = [1899, 1950, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2018, 2020, 2022, 2024]



def get_titles(streaming: str, cursor: str = None, titles: list = None, start: bool = True):
    """ Get all titles available of a streaming. """
    
    if not titles:
        titles = []
    
    if cursor and not start:
        post_data['variables']['popularAfterCursor'] = cursor
    else:
        post_data['variables']['popularAfterCursor'] = ""
    
    set_streaming(streaming)
    req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(post_data), headers=headers)
    if req.status_code != 200:
        raise requests.ConnectionError('connection failed')
    
    results = req.json()['data']['popularTitles']
    titles.extend(results['edges'])   
       
    if results['pageInfo']['hasNextPage']:
        cursor = results['pageInfo']['endCursor']
        get_titles(streaming=streaming, cursor=cursor, titles=titles, start=False)
    
    return titles


def parse_title_content(title: dict):
    """ Parse the title content to a dictionary. """
    
    content = {}
    
    title = title['node']
    content['id'] = title['id']
    content['title'] = title['content']['title']
    content['type'] = title['objectType']
    content['description'] = title['content']['shortDescription']
    content['release_year'] = title['content']['originalReleaseYear']
    content['age_certification'] = title['content']['ageCertification']
    content['runtime'] = title['content']['runtime']
    content['genres'] = [i['technicalName'] for i in title['content']['genres']]
    content['production_countries'] = title['content']['productionCountries']
    content['seasons'] = title.get('totalSeasonCount', None)
    content['imdb_id'] = title['content']['externalIds']['imdbId']
    content['imdb_score'] = title['content']['scoring']['imdbScore']
    content['imdb_votes'] = title['content']['scoring']['imdbVotes']
    content['tmdb_popularity'] = title['content']['scoring']['tmdbPopularity']
    content['tmdb_score'] = title['content']['scoring']['tmdbScore']
    
    credits = [
        {
            'person_id': i['personId'],
            'id': content['id'],
            'name': i['name'],
            'character': i['characterName'],
            'role': i['role']
        } for i in title['content']['credits']
    ]
    
    return content, credits


def parse_and_save_data(data: list, save: bool = True, path: str = ''):
    """ Parse a list of titles and save it to a file. """
    
    titles, credits = [], []
    for d in data:
        t, c = parse_title_content(d)
        titles.append(t)
        credits.extend(c)
    
    if save:
        titles_df = pd.DataFrame(titles)
        titles_df.to_csv(path+'titles.csv', index=False)

        credits_df = pd.DataFrame(credits)
        credits_df.to_csv(path+'credits.csv', index=False)

    return titles, credits


def get_all_titles_by_streaming(streaming: str, save: bool = True, path: str = ''):
    """ Get all titles available on a given streaming. """
    raw = []
    for i in range(len(clusters) - 1):
        filter_range = {'min': clusters[i]+1, 'max': clusters[i+1]}
        
        post_data['variables']['popularTitlesFilter']['releaseYear'] = filter_range  # Set the filter
        
        cluster_titles = get_titles(streaming=streaming)
        raw.extend(cluster_titles)
    
    if save:
        file_path = f'{path}/{streaming}/'
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            os.mkdir(file_path)
            
    titles, credits = parse_and_save_data(data=raw, save=save, path=file_path)
    
    return titles, credits


def get_all_titles(save: bool = True, path:str = ''):
    """ Get all titles available on the available streamings. """
    
    all_titles = {}
    for key in tqdm(streamings.keys()):
        titles, credits = get_all_titles_by_streaming(streaming=key, save=save, path=path)
        all_titles[key] = {'titles': titles, 'credits': credits}
    
    return all_titles


data = get_all_titles(save=True, path='data')
len(data['netflix']['titles'])
```

I ran the code and got the error. I think the error is coming from the dictonary and I changed the syntax  but the error still persists. I want to get the data and store it in a csv file. I used the following github project -

[Github project](https://github.com/victor-soeiro/WebScraping-Projects/tree/main/08%20-%20justwatch)

Comment: Why have you flooded your question with dots? Which line gives the problem? What did you learn when you used a debugger?

Comment: Your question consists mainly of code. Please add more details so we can better understand how we can help. You can also add the error message.

Comment: In the error line (known only to you!) you have somethinhg like `x[y]`, a subscripting expression. `x` has the `None` value, when it shouldn't. Determine where `x` is set, and why it is `None`.  Correct that. The problem is before the error line. not in it!